# Смена цвета у svg иконки при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении черно-белая svg-иконка, становилась цветной? Если есть скрипт, могли бы вы рассказать, что к чему там?

Comment: http://codepen.io/luiscarvalho/pen/hJFrx/?editors=1100

Comment: Здесь же меняется цвет заливки просто ?

Comment: так точно, можно даже подставлять не цвет, а изображение

Comment: Просто через транзишн или Вы прописываете что-то в svg коде ?

Comment: И как изменить изображение ? )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
img:not(:hover) {
  transition: 2s;
  filter: saturate(0%);
  -webkit-filter: saturate(0%);
  }
img:hover {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<img width=200 src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg">
```